# Saving and using values tip calculator app

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating a simple tip calculator to learn the basics of iOS development and I am having trouble saving values from one page and reusing it in another.

Currently, my root page(aka TipViewController.m):

```
#import "TipViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface TipViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *billTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tipLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *tipControl;

- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender;
- (void)updateValues;
- (void)onSettingsButton;

@end

@implementation TipViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Tip Calculator";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateValues];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onSettingsButton)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)onTap:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; //keyboard goes away
    [self updateValues];
}

- (void)updateValues{
    float billAmount = [self.billTextField.text floatValue];

    // array to hold all tip values
    NSArray *tipValues = @[@(0.1), @(0.15), @(0.2)];
    float tipAmount = billAmount*[tipValues[self.tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex] floatValue];
    float totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;

    self.tipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", tipAmount];
    self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", totalAmount];
}

- (void)onSettingsButton {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[SettingsViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}

@end
```

When I tap the settings button on top right it will lead me to my settings page:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *defaultTipPercentage;

- (IBAction)ontap:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Settings";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)ontap:(id)sender {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
@end
```

Right now I want the value placed inside the TextField to be the default tip percentage to be used when I go back to the root page.

I was thinking of putting this under `ontap()` to save the value(SettingsViewController.m):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"some_string_to_save" forKey:@"some_key_that_you_choose"];
[defaults setInteger:123 forKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and create an `if statement` inside `updateValues()` in my `TipViewController.m` to load the default value.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *stringValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"some_key_that_you_choose"];
int intValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];

- (void)updateValues{
    float billAmount = [self.billTextField.text floatValue];

    if (intValue) {
        float tipAmount = .01 * intValue;
    }else {

    // array to hold all tip values
    NSArray *tipValues = @[@(0.1), @(0.15), @(0.2)];
    float tipAmount = billAmount*[tipValues[self.tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex] floatValue];
    float totalAmount = tipAmount + billAmount;
    }

    self.tipLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", tipAmount];
    self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%0.2f", totalAmount];
}
```

Not really sure if I am doing this correctly but this is what I've tried so far.

Comment: This is not a good use of NSUserDefaults -- they're for persisting values between launches of an app, not for passing data between controllers. You should search "Pass data between controllers" on this site. There are thousands of questions and answers on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rdelmar comment is correct unless you do want to persist the value between launches of the app.  (In this case, I would think so.)
Move the lines

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int intValue = [defaults integerForKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];
```

inside of `updateValues`, so that value of `intValue` is current every time `updateValues` is called.